# What is the equivalent of MS-SQL `QUOTENAME` in `DB2`

Tags: sql, db2, database-migration

I change from MS-SQL to DB2. In the procedures are some `QUOTENAME` methods to prevent sql-injection.  Does in DB2 exist a function like this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you misunderstand the purpose of `QUOTENAME` -- it's not to "prevent SQL injection"; it is "[to make the input string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)."

Since the only way to quote an identifier in Db2 (and, I believe, in standard SQL) is to enclose it in double quotation marks, you can easily achieve the same functionality by using a `REPLACE` function:

```
create function quotename (input varchar (128)) returns varchar(128)
return '"' || replace(input, '"', '""') || '"'
```

Comment: to be fair, quotename helps a little against SQL injection: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring

Comment: Using it to "prevent SQL injection" will simply give you a false sense of security, since it can only address one edge case at a time. One should use proper techniques against SQL injection, such as parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 11.5 introduced `QUOTE_IDENT` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_quote_ident.html and `QUOTE_LITERAL` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_quote_literal.html